# Can I play pure Piano tunes with a Quasimidi Raven?

Tags: midi, piano, usb, synthesizer

Being a total noob in this topic...**I have a [Quasimidi Raven synth](http://www.vintagesynth.com/misc/raven.php)) on my desk and would like to play just plain vanilla Piano sounds on, or with, it. Is it possible?** Or do I have to hook it up to my PC (using MIDI to what? USB? Using what software?) and use the PC to generate the sound in realtime?

As far I can see, there is no config aboard the Raven that puts piano on the whole manual. It usually is right-hand piano, left-hand something else. Maybe I can upload the piano-only definition from my PC to the synth?

My primary target is not recording, but re-using the "shelf-ware" Raven for finding out if I can get the hang on playing piano as the first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would happily trade you for a synth with a piano mode.  :-D

I don't have one of these, but the nature of this synth is a bit different than a sampler with basic envelope.  If there is a piano sample on there, I suspect the reason that it won't go on the full keyboard is because it would sound terrible!  You would be loading one "piano" sample for the whole keyboard and simply changing the pitch of it.

Modern piano emulators have a different sample for every single note, and at a handful of velocities.

If you want a basic piano sound to get started, you can map the MIDI input from your Raven to the basic general MIDI synth built into your computer.  [MIDI-OX](http://www.midiox.com/) allows you to do this very easily.

Comment: Thanks. What cable and PC interface would I use?

Comment: Any MIDI to USB interface will do just fine.  I like the M-Audio Uno (http://www.m-audio.com/products/en_au/Uno.html), but there are cheaper alternatives on Amazon.

Comment: May I also ask if it is a viable option to upload samples and/or bank definitions to the synth via USB so I could get exactly the keyboard config I want (ignoring the bad quality of the simple linear upscaling the synth would probably do to the basic sample I'd upload)? Or is that nonsense?

Comment: @TheBlastOne, I don't believe you can upload samples, but you can edit patches.  Details on the MIDI implementation is here:  http://www.deepsonic.ch/deep/manuals/quasimidi_raven_manual.pdf  Although it is quite technical.  You would be best off finding a patch editor already created for you.  I am not sure if one exists.